# How to link multiple models with Foreign Key and make corresponding views to get the data rendered at templates in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am creating a web application in which a user can sell his old phone on the website and get maximum available value for the phone.

The process is kind of similar to Cashify.(https://www.cashify.in/sell-old-mobile-phone).

Once the user clicks on a particular brand, it lists all the available devices under that brand.

When the user clicks on a particular device, it goes to a URL showing different variants of the Phone. When the user selects the variant, maximum available price of the device it shown to the user.

Here's the code:

**models.py**

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    title               = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    brand_image         = models.ImageField()
    slug                = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='slug')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Brands"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Storage(models.Model):
    ram_storage = models.CharField(max_length=2, default=1)
    rom_storage = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=2)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Storages"

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.ram_storage + "/" + self.rom_storage)

class Mobile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    max_selling_price = models.IntegerField(default=10000)

    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, default="Apple", related_name='brand', verbose_name="Brands", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    storage = models.ForeignKey(Storage, related_name='storage', default=1, verbose_name="Storage", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('brand-detail', kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
```

**views.py**

```
def brand_detail_view(request, slug):
    phone = Mobile.objects.filter(brand__slug = slug)
    context = {
        "phones": phone
    }

    return render(request, "brand-detail.html", context)

def phone_detail_view(request, slug):
    phone = get_object_or_404(Mobile, brand__slug=slug)
    context = {
        "phone": phone
    }
    return render(request, "phone-detail.html", context)
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a model, Type or Model, whatever you want to call it. IE: brand iPhone, model XS.